# How to get first n chars from a str column/Utf8Chunked in rust polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

What's the alternative of pandas :

```
data['ColumnA'].str[:2]
```

in rust polars?
My first guess was:

```
let x = Utf8Chunked::new("ColumnA", &["Pear", "apple", "toly", "x"]);
let y = x.slice(0, 2);
```

I'd like to get an array/ChunkedArray/Utf8Chunked which looks something like `["Pe", "ap", "to", "x"]`. But `.slice()` actually just takes first n elements of an array. Is it possible without iterating over the array? (as my understanding iterating would slow down the performance).
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`str_slice`](https://docs.rs/polars/0.21.1/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.str_slice) method on `ChunkedArray`:

```
let x = Utf8Chunked::new("ColumnA", &["Pear", "apple", "toly", "x"]);
dbg!(x.str_slice(0, Some(2)));
```

Note that you must enable the `strings` feature of `polars` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.21.1", features = ["strings"] }
```